# regra do trapézio em matlab!

Tags: matlab

Boa noite. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Preciso criar um função em matlab que resolva integrais pela "Regra do Trapézio Composta".

Sei como funciona a "Regra do Trapézio", mas como fazer a implementação em matlab?

Comment: Como funciona a "regra do trapézio"? O que você tentou até agora? Qual é a diferença de uma "regra do trapézio" convencional da "regra do trapézio composta"?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Regra do Trapézio Composta e cálculo do erro:  https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~calves/courses/integra/capiii32.html

Comment: @José serve Java/C/Python? Eu iria até mesmo falar Bash, mas Bash não se dá muito bem com números quebrados... eu definitivamente não sei R nem Matlab, e não tenho muito estímulo para aprender na minha situação atual

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado aí é com o camarada Estudante que foi quem perguntou. Mas creio que não sirva.. Até sei R ou MatLab pra responder, mas vai demorar um pouco pra formular uma resposta e pode não ser o melhor algoritmo. Não uso mais essas ferramentas.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que Matlab é um software bem versátil para cálculo com matrizes e análise de dados, a maioria de algoritmos amplamente utilizados para análise de data conta com uma versão *built-in*.

O que você está querendo implementar é a função [trapz](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html).

Porém lhe encorajo a construir a sua própria versão e comparar os resultados(devem ser iguais ou apenas com uma pequena diferença).
A  sua versão muito provavelmente será pior e mais devagar, mas é um ótimo exercício para aprender a programar melhor.

Uma idea a seguir (baseado na *minha* experiência, mas talvez ñ seja a melhor opção para você) é entender como o método é usado se você calcular com lápis e papel. Veja o que vc consegue transformar em `for` loops e `if` e `else` statements e construa a sua função com isso.